# R pivot_longer names_pattern

Tags: r, regex, dplyr

I want to use `pivot_longer` to turn a wide to a long table, and have the resulting dataframe to be like this. Here's the source dataframe. What is the names_pattern I should use to properly extract the substrings into to `variable`, `x`, and `freq`.

Source dataframe
[image]

```
structure(list(or = c(0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0), agegrp = structure(list(
    x = c("<65", ">=65", "<65", ">=65", "<65", ">=65"), freq = c(10L, 
    16L, 6L, 6L, 9L, 14L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L)), asian = structure(list(x = c(0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1), freq = c(15L, 
11L, 4L, 8L, 13L, 10L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L)), SEX = structure(list(x = c("Female", "Male", "Female", 
"Male", "Female", "Male"), freq = c(7L, 19L, 6L, 6L, 10L, 13L
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

What I would like to achieve

```
or     variable    x      freq
1      agegrp      <65    6
1      agegrp      >=65   6
1      asian       0      4
1      asian       1      8
1      SEX         Female 6
1      SEX         Male   6
```

Comment: Please show the `dput` of a small subset of your source data i.e. `dput(head(yourdata))` Based on the image, it looks like some nested data.frame columns.  Perhaps you need `df1 %>% unpack(where(is.data.frame))` or `unnest` before converting to long format

Comment: Sure, edited with a reproducible example.

Answer (score 1):

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  select(-starts_with("SEX")) %>% 
  mutate(across(,as.character)) %>% 
  pivot_longer(df, cols = -or, 
                    names_to = c('variable', '.value'), 
                    names_sep = '\\.') %>% 
  mutate(variable = ifelse(variable=="agegrp", "age", variable)) %>% 
  arrange(variable)
```

or

```
df %>% 
  select(-starts_with("SEX")) %>% 
  mutate(across(,as.character)) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -or,
               names_to = c('variable', '.value'), 
               names_pattern = '(\\w+)\\.(\\w+)'
               )%>% 
  mutate(variable = ifelse(variable=="agegrp", "age", variable)) %>% 
  arrange(variable)
```

```
  or    variable x     freq 
  <chr> <chr>    <chr> <chr>
1 1     age      <65   6    
2 1     age      >=65  6    
3 1     asian    0     4    
4 1     asian    1     8
```

data:

```
structure(list(or = c(1L, 1L), agegrp.x = c("<65", ">=65"), agegrp.freq = c(6L, 
6L), asian.x = 0:1, asian.freq = c(4L, 8L), SEX.x = c("Female", 
"Male"), SEX.freq = c(6L, 6L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm running into this error.
Error in `stop_vctrs()`:
! Can't combine `agegrp.x` <character> and `asian.x` <integer>.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
Warning message:
In gsub(paste0("^", names_prefix), "", names(cols)) :
  argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

Comment: Sure, edited with a reproducible example.